# Как сделать чтоб бекграунд шевелился при вращении телефона в руке?

Tags: java, android

Хочу сделать такую штуку, когда картинка на бэкграунде двигается, когда двигаешь телефон в руке. Типо такой 3D эффект.

Пример: держишь телефон в руке - картика стоит ровно, чуть повернул телефон по оси (вправо или влево), и картинка тоже чуть-чуть сдвигается.

У меня плохо получается объяснить, но, надеюсь, получилось.

Как сделать такой эффект?

Я нашел информацию о паралаксе, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно.

P.S. 
Вот что то похожее есть в примере из ответа @Kamran
http://kamran.site/demos/accelerometer/index-1.php

Смысл в том, что картинка на бэкграунде по ширине немного больше ширины экрана, как бы у нее есть запас хода влево и вправо. Это и дает возможность движения этой картинки, только я не могу пока что представить, как это должно работать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86289/discussion-on-question-by-aleksey-timoshchenko-----).

Comment: В хуавее формат есть 3d photo

Comment: @eri что? я вообще не понял, что вы хотели сказать

Comment: там формат интересный. не паралакс.

Comment: @eri есть видео?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuz-c1D2nsg

Comment: @eri да, действительно круто. Но мне сейчас нужно не совсем это... Мне нужнен именно паралакс...

Comment: с паралаксом не пойму что непонятного. берешь акселерометр, берешь с него ось.  считаешь смещение по простой формуле, акселерометр снять проблем нет даже в вэб браузере.

Comment: @eri даже не знаю, что тебе ответить ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Параллакс** -- именно то, что тебе нужно.
Вот пример того что ты хочешь получить: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJ7F5vpk6OU

Да и тот пример который ты показал в линке -- это ТОЖЕ ПАРАЛАКС.

Как действует внутри сам эфект паралакса:

1. Отрисовываешь все нужные картинки "слоями".
2. Пишешь некоторую функцию для смещения каждого из слоев. Чем дальше находится картинка(условно, "дальше") -- тем медленнее должна она двигаться. В общем-то функция должна быть одна, только изменяться размер смещения должен по коэфициэнту.
3. Привязываешь все функции к значению акселерометра/гироскопа телефона и изменяешь при каждой следующей отрисовке кадра.

Готовой формулы нет -- нужно экспериментировать в зависимости от того что ты хочешь получить:

- Может быть только горизонтальный паралакс-эфект
- Или по двум осям (вверх и вниз)
- Или же по всем осям -- в т.ч. приближение и отдаление при опускании и поднимании телефона).

Гуглится по запросу "java parallax scrolling accelerometer".

Есть пример библиотеки которая это делает, как раз, на джаве: https://github.com/nvanbenschoten/motion

При чем сразу с апликухой-примером которую можно поставить на мобильный и проверить вживую: https://github.com/nvanbenschoten/motion/releases/download/v1.1.2/motion-sample.apk

В самой апликухе внизу ползунок перетащи вправо до упора что бы лучше было видно сам эфект.

---

UPD:
Вот еще одна паралакс библиотека на джаве:

https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Parallax-Layer-Layout

---

И еще одна тоже на джаве:

https://github.com/tvbarthel/ParallaxSampleGitHub

И пример: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyNBZLzWxYI

**У тебя есть выбор!**

Вот пример кода из библиотеки приведенной выше

`attrs`

```
<declare-styleable name="ParallaxImageView">
    <attr name="motionIntensity" format="float"/>
    <attr name="motionTiltSensitivity" format="float"/>
    <attr name="motionScaledIntensity" format="boolean"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

`ParallaxImageView`

```
public class ParallaxImageView extends 
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView implements SensorEventListener
{
private static final String TAG = ParallaxImageView.class.getName();

/**
 * If the x and y axis' intensities are scaled to the image's aspect ratio (true) or
 * equal to the smaller of the axis' intensities (false). If true, the image will be able to
 * translate up to it's view bounds, independent of aspect ratio. If not true,
 * the image will limit it's translation equally so that motion in either axis results
 * in proportional translation.
 */
private boolean mScaledIntensities = false;

/**
 * The intensity of the parallax effect, giving the perspective of depth.
 */
private float mParallaxIntensity = 1.2f;

/**
 * The maximum percentage of offset translation that the image can move for each
 * sensor input. Set to a negative number to disable.
 */
private float mMaximumJump = .1f;

// Instance variables used during matrix manipulation.
private SensorInterpreter mSensorInterpreter;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Matrix mTranslationMatrix;
private float mXTranslation;
private float mYTranslation;
private float mXOffset;
private float mYOffset;

public ParallaxImageView(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public ParallaxImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ParallaxImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Instantiate future objects
    mTranslationMatrix = new Matrix();
    mSensorInterpreter = new SensorInterpreter();

    // Sets scale type
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    // Set available attributes
    if (attrs != null)
    {
        final TypedArray customAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ParallaxImageView);

        if (customAttrs != null)
        {
            if (customAttrs.hasValue(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_motionIntensity))
            {


  setParallaxIntensity(
customAttrs.getFloat(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_motionIntensity, 
mParallaxIntensity));
            }

            if (customAttrs.hasValue(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_motionScaledIntensity))
            {
                setScaledIntensities(customAttrs.getBoolean(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_motionScaledIntensity, mScaledIntensities));
            }

            if (customAttrs.hasValue(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_motionTiltSensitivity))
            {
                 setTiltSensitivity(customAttrs.getFloat(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_motionTiltSensitivity, mSensorInterpreter.getTiltSensitivity()));
            }

            customAttrs.recycle();
        }
    }

    // Configure matrix as early as possible by posting to MessageQueue
    post(this::configureMatrix);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    configureMatrix();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if (mSensorInterpreter == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    final float[] vectors = mSensorInterpreter.interpretSensorEvent(getContext(), event);

    // Return if interpretation of data failed
    if (vectors == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Set translation on ImageView matrix
    setTranslate(vectors[2], -vectors[1]);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
{
}

/**
 * Registers a sensor manager with the parallax ImageView. Should be called in onResume
 * or onStart lifecycle callbacks from an Activity or Fragment.
 */
public void registerSensorManager()
{
    registerSensorManager(SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

/**
 * Registers a sensor manager with the parallax ImageView. Should be called in onResume
 * or onStart lifecycle callbacks from an Activity or Fragment.
 *
 * @param samplingPeriodUs the sensor sampling period rate
 */
public void registerSensorManager(int samplingPeriodUs)
{
    if (getContext() == null || mSensorManager != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Acquires a sensor manager
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if (mSensorManager != null)
    {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), samplingPeriodUs);
    }
}

/**
 * Unregisters the ParallaxImageView's SensorManager. Should be called in onPause or onStop
 * lifecycle callbacks from an Activity or Fragment to avoid leaking sensor usage.
 */
public void unregisterSensorManager()
{
    unregisterSensorManager(false);
}

/**
 * Unregisters the ParallaxImageView's SensorManager. Should be called in onPause from
 * an Activity or Fragment to avoid continuing sensor usage.
 *
 * @param resetTranslation if the image translation should be reset to the origin
 */
public void unregisterSensorManager(boolean resetTranslation)
{
    if (mSensorManager == null || mSensorInterpreter == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    mSensorManager = null;
    mSensorInterpreter.reset();

    if (resetTranslation)
    {
        setTranslate(0, 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the intensity of the parallax effect. The stronger the effect, the more distance
 * the image will have to move around.
 *
 * @param parallaxIntensity the new intensity
 */
public void setParallaxIntensity(float parallaxIntensity)
{
    if (parallaxIntensity < 1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parallax effect must have a intensity of 1.0 or greater");
    }

    mParallaxIntensity = parallaxIntensity;
    configureMatrix();
}

/**
 * Sets the parallax tilt sensitivity for the image view. The stronger the sensitivity,
 * the more a given tilt will adjust the image and the smaller needed tilt to reach the
 * image bounds.
 *
 * @param sensitivity the new tilt sensitivity
 */
public void setTiltSensitivity(float sensitivity)
{
    mSensorInterpreter.setTiltSensitivity(sensitivity);
}

/**
 * Sets whether translation should be limited to the image's bounds or should be limited
 * to the smaller of the two axis' translation limits.
 *
 * @param scaledIntensities the scaledIntensities flag
 */
public void setScaledIntensities(boolean scaledIntensities)
{
    mScaledIntensities = scaledIntensities;
}

/**
 * Sets the maximum percentage of the image that image matrix is allowed to translate
 * for each sensor reading.
 *
 * @param maximumJump the new maximum jump
 */
public void setMaximumJump(float maximumJump)
{
    mMaximumJump = maximumJump;
}

/**
 * Sets the image view's translation coordinates. These values must be between -1 and 1,
 * representing the transaction percentage from the center.
 *
 * @param x the horizontal translation
 * @param y the vertical translation
 */
private void setTranslate(float x, float y)
{
    if (Math.abs(x) > 1 || Math.abs(y) > 1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parallax effect cannot translate more than 100% of its off-screen size");
    }

    float xScale, yScale;

    if (mScaledIntensities)
    {
        // Set both scales to their offset values
        xScale = mXOffset;
        yScale = mYOffset;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set both scales to the max offset (should be negative, so smaller 
 absolute value)
        xScale = Math.max(mXOffset, mYOffset);
        yScale = Math.max(mXOffset, mYOffset);
    }

    // Make sure below maximum jump limit
    if (mMaximumJump > 0)
    {
        // Limit x jump
        if (x - mXTranslation / xScale > mMaximumJump)
        {
            x = mXTranslation / xScale + mMaximumJump;
        }
        else if (x - mXTranslation / xScale < -mMaximumJump)
        {
            x = mXTranslation / xScale - mMaximumJump;
        }

        // Limit y jump
        if (y - mYTranslation / yScale > mMaximumJump)
        {
            y = mYTranslation / yScale + mMaximumJump;
        }
        else if (y - mYTranslation / yScale < -mMaximumJump)
        {
            y = mYTranslation / yScale - mMaximumJump;
        }
    }

    mXTranslation = x * xScale;
    mYTranslation = y * yScale;

    configureMatrix();
}

/**
 * Configures the ImageView's imageMatrix to allow for movement of the
 * source image.
 */
private void configureMatrix()
{
    if (getDrawable() == null || getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    int dWidth = getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    int dHeight = getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    int vWidth = getWidth();
    int vHeight = getHeight();

    float scale;
    float dx, dy;

    if (dWidth * vHeight > vWidth * dHeight)
    {
        scale = (float) vHeight / (float) dHeight;
        mXOffset = (vWidth - dWidth * scale * mParallaxIntensity) * 0.5f;
        mYOffset = (vHeight - dHeight * scale * mParallaxIntensity) * 0.5f;
    }
    else
    {
        scale = (float) vWidth / (float) dWidth;
        mXOffset = (vWidth - dWidth * scale * mParallaxIntensity) * 0.5f;
        mYOffset = (vHeight - dHeight * scale * mParallaxIntensity) * 0.5f;
    }

    dx = mXOffset + mXTranslation;
    dy = mYOffset + mYTranslation;

    mTranslationMatrix.set(getImageMatrix());
    mTranslationMatrix.setScale(mParallaxIntensity * scale, mParallaxIntensity * scale);
    mTranslationMatrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
    setImageMatrix(mTranslationMatrix);
}

}
```

`SensorInterpreter`

```
class SensorInterpreter
{
private static final String TAG = SensorInterpreter.class.getName();

/**
 * The standardized tilt vector corresponding to yaw, pitch, and roll deltas from target matrix.
 */
private float[] mTiltVector = new float[3];

/**
 * Whether the SensorInterpreter has set a target to calculate tilt offset from.
 */
private boolean mTargeted = false;

/**
 * The target rotation matrix to calculate tilt offset from.
 */
private float[] mTargetMatrix = new float[16];

/**
 * Rotation matrices used during calculation.
 */
private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mOrientedRotationMatrix = new float[16];

/**
 * Holds a shortened version of the rotation vector for compatibility purposes.
 */
private float[] mTruncatedRotationVector;

/**
 * The sensitivity the parallax effect has towards tilting.
 */
private float mTiltSensitivity = 2.0f;

/**
 * Converts sensor data in a {@link SensorEvent} to yaw, pitch, and roll.
 *
 * @param context the context of the
 * @param event   the event to interpret
 *
 * @return an interpreted vector of yaw, pitch, and roll delta values
 */
@SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousNameCombination")
public float[] interpretSensorEvent(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable SensorEvent event)
{
    if (event == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Retrieves the RotationVector from SensorEvent
    float[] rotationVector = getRotationVectorFromSensorEvent(event);

    // Set target rotation if none has been set
    if (!mTargeted)
    {
        setTargetVector(rotationVector);
        return null;
    }

    // Get rotation matrix from event's values
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, rotationVector);

    // Acquire rotation of screen
    final int rotation = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    // Calculate angle differential between target and current orientation
    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0)
    {
        SensorManager.getAngleChange(mTiltVector, mRotationMatrix, mTargetMatrix);
    }
    else
    {
        // Adjust axes on screen orientation by remapping coordinates
        switch (rotation)
        {
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix, AXIS_Y, AXIS_MINUS_X, mOrientedRotationMatrix);
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix, AXIS_MINUS_X, AXIS_MINUS_Y, mOrientedRotationMatrix);
                break;

            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix, AXIS_MINUS_Y, AXIS_X, mOrientedRotationMatrix);
                break;
        }

        SensorManager.getAngleChange(mTiltVector, mOrientedRotationMatrix, mTargetMatrix);
    }

    // Perform value scaling and clamping on value array
    for (int i = 0 ; i < mTiltVector.length ; i++)
    {
        // Map domain of tilt vector from radian (-PI, PI) to fraction (-1, 1)
        mTiltVector[i] /= Math.PI;

        // Adjust for tilt sensitivity
        mTiltVector[i] *= mTiltSensitivity;

        // Clamp values to image bounds
        if (mTiltVector[i] > 1)
        {
            mTiltVector[i] = 1f;
        }
        else if (mTiltVector[i] < -1)
        {
            mTiltVector[i] = -1f;
        }
    }

    return mTiltVector;
}

/**
 * Pulls out the rotation vector from a {@link SensorEvent}, with a maximum length
 * vector of four elements to avoid potential compatibility issues.
 *
 * @param event the sensor event
 *
 * @return the events rotation vector, potentially truncated
 */
@NonNull
@VisibleForTesting
float[] getRotationVectorFromSensorEvent(@NonNull SensorEvent event)
{
    if (event.values.length > 4)
    {
        // On some Samsung devices SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector
        // appears to throw an exception if rotation vector has length > 4.
        // For the purposes of this class the first 4 values of the
        // rotation vector are sufficient (see crbug.com/335298 for details).
        if (mTruncatedRotationVector == null)
        {
            mTruncatedRotationVector = new float[4];
        }
        System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mTruncatedRotationVector, 0, 4);
        return mTruncatedRotationVector;
    }
    else
    {
        return event.values;
    }
}

/**
 * Sets the target direction used for angle deltas to determine tilt.
 *
 * @param values a rotation vector (presumably from a ROTATION_VECTOR sensor)
 */
protected void setTargetVector(float[] values)
{
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mTargetMatrix, values);
    mTargeted = true;
}

/**
 * Resets the state of the SensorInterpreter, removing any target direction used for angle
 * deltas to determine tilt.
 */
public void reset()
{
    mTargeted = false;
}

/**
 * Determines the tilt sensitivity of the SensorInterpreter.
 *
 * @return the tilt sensitivity
 */
public float getTiltSensitivity()
{
    return mTiltSensitivity;
}

/**
 * Sets the new sensitivity that the SensorInterpreter will scale tilt calculations by. If this
 * sensitivity is above 1, the interpreter will have to clamp percentages to 100% and -100% at
 * the tilt extremes.
 *
 * @param tiltSensitivity the new tilt sensitivity
 */
public void setTiltSensitivity(float tiltSensitivity)
{
    if (tiltSensitivity <= 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tilt sensitivity must be positive");
    }

    mTiltSensitivity = tiltSensitivity;
}

}
```

И потом в коде

```
        mScreenBackground.setImageResource(iRes);
```

и там где вам нужно (например в `onResume()`) вызываем `mScreenBackground.registerSensorManager();` и не забываем отписаться (например в `onStop()`)

Comment: Те примеры которые я находил с паралаксом они были основаны на `ScrollView` и не встретил ни одного примера с акселерометром. Мне на самом деле нужен самый простой горизонтальный паралакс ... Чтоб реагировал только на горизонтальное смешение. Если вдруг встретишь такой то было бы круто

Comment: Библиотека в конце ответа работает с акселерометром. Код открытый для просмотра. Линк на пример работающий на мобильном так же добавил.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Ну что, разобрался с кодом?

Comment: Там( https://github.com/nvanbenschoten/motion/releases ) есть сорцы демок в свободном доступе, качаешь тот проэкт, убираешь ползунок (а вместо того что бы брать данные с него просто отправляешь максимальное значение) и тебе готовый код того что ты просил.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko как я вижу, с кодом ты уже разобрался. Думаю, можно принимать ответ :)

Comment: Конечно можно) только нужно еще подождать)

Comment: Слушай не могу как исправить с коде такую штуку, получается, что даже если картинка по высоте точно такая же как и высота экрана но по ширене она шире (то есть паралаксу есть куда двигаться влево вправо) то все равно он как то увеличавает ее к середине... Зачем? Я не хочу, чтоб он ее увеличивал картинка и так сама по себе шире чем экран... Есть предположения как это исправить?

Comment: Скорее всего там играет роль и высота. Сори, но здесь помочь не могу, я вообще шарпер :)

Answer (score 1):

Код гибкий, поработайте со значениями оси... (accY и accX) в основном все что есть для контродя датчиков

```
window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {

accX = Math.round(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x*10) / 10;  
accY = Math.round(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y*10) / 10;  

movement = 10;

xA = -(accX / 10) * movement;
yA = -(accY / 10) * movement;

run();

}
```

вы смотрели пример - http://kamran.site/demos/accelerometer/index-1.php  ?

Comment: как бы тег `android` у вопроса ничего вам не говорит?

Comment: @pavlofff этот пример отлично работает под android. вот с java - да, немного мимо

Comment: @PashaPash да похоже на то ,  что мне нужно. Только теперь не совсем ясно, как это применить в андроиде... допустим я с помощью этого кода могу получать смещение... Но я не уверен во первых, что это правильно висеть на этом ивенте и слушать его постоянно, а во вторых как это смещение применить к `ImageView`

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko я не android дев :) попробуйте через TranslateAnimation. если не получится - задайте отдельным вопросом

Comment: @PashaPash я так понимаю, что это отлично работает в любом браузере, в том числе и под системой андроид? в вопросе речь идет о нативных виджетах системы и их бэкграунде. Я вот немного андроид дев и очень слабо себе представляю, как в бэкграунд нативного виджета пристроить весь этот HTML/JS .. поставить фоном WebView решение так себе или хотелось бы узнать поподробнее, каким образом это отлично работает с бэкграундом виджетов андроида

Answer (score -1):

**Пример:**

JS ---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var has_touch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
    var accX, accY, width, height, xA, yA, movement;

    if(has_touch || screen.width <= 699) {

        (resize = function() {

            height = $(window).height();
            width = $(window).width();

            $('#container').width(width).height(height);


        })();

        window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {

            accX = Math.round(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x*10) / 10;  
            accY = Math.round(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y*10) / 10;  

            movement = 10;

            xA = -(accX / 10) * movement;
            yA = -(accY / 10) * movement;


            run();

        }  

    } else {

        $('.content').show();

        $('#container').addClass('fullscreen').mousemove(function(e) {

            width = $(this).width();
            height = $(this).height();

            accX = (((e.pageX - this.offsetLeft)*2 / width) * 10) - 10;
            accY = (((e.pageY - this.offsetTop)*2 / width) * 10) - 10;

            xA = -(accX / 10);
            yA = -(accY / 10);

            movement = 2;

            run();

        });


    }

    function run() {

        $('.box').css({'left' : xA+'px', 'top' : yA+'px', 'box-shadow' : ''+xA+'px '+yA+'px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'});

        bX = -(xA*2)-100;
        bY = -(yA*2)-300;

        $('#container').css({'background-position' : bX+'px '+bY+'px'});

    }

});
```

html ---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Accelerometer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font/ss-standard.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../gs.css" />
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='javascript-1.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <div class='box'></div>
</div>

<div class='content tk-museo-sans'>тут контент</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Пример: http://kamran.site/demos/accelerometer/index-1.php
Код: http://kamran.site/demos/accelerometer/download.zip

Comment: Мне не кажется, что вы правильно меня поняли. Поменял заголовок вопроса